# Conflict between some JavaScript and jQuery on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I am using a JavaScript function and some jQuery to perform two actions on a page.  The first is a simple JS function to hide/show divs and change the active state of a tab:

This is the JS that show/hides divs and changes the active state on some tabs:

```
var ids=new Array('section1','section2','section3');

function switchid(id, el){  
    hideallids();
    showdiv(id);

    var li = el.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[0];
    while (li) {
        if (!li.tagName || li.tagName.toLowerCase() != "li")
            li = li.nextSibling; // skip the text node
        if (li) {
          li.className = "";
          li = li.nextSibling;
        }
    }
    el.parentNode.className = "active";
}

function hideallids(){
    //loop through the array and hide each element by id
    for (var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
        hidediv(ids[i]);
    }         
}

function hidediv(id) {
    //safe function to hide an element with a specified id
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}

function showdiv(id) {
    //safe function to show an element with a specified id        
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

The html:

```
<ul>
<li class="active"><a onclick="switchid('section1', this);return false;">ONE</a></li>
<li><a onclick="switchid('section2', this);return false;">TWO</a></li>
<li><a onclick="switchid('section3', this);return false;">THREE</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="section1" style="display:block;">TEST</div>
<div id="section2" style="display:none;">TEST 2</div>
<div id="section3" style="display:none;">TEST 3</div>
```

Now the problem....

I've added the jQuery image gallery called galleria to one of the tabs.  The gallery works great when it resides in the div that is intially set to display:block.  However, when it is in one of the divs that is set to display: none; part of the gallery doesn't work when the div is toggled to be visible.  Specifically, the following css ceases to be written (this is created by galleria jQuery):

```
element.style  {
display:block;
height:50px;
margin-left:-17px;
width:auto;
}
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out why the gallery fails when it's div is set to display: none.  Since this declaration is overwritten when a tab is clicked (via the  Javascript functions above), why would this cause a problem? As I mentioned, it works perfectly when it lives the in display: block; div.

Any ideas?  I don't expect anybody to be familiar with the jQuery galleria image gallery... but perhaps an idea of how one might repair this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are including jQuery then you can shorten your javascript to this:

```
$(function() {

var sections = $('#section1, #section2, #section3');
function switchid(id, el){  
    sections.hide();
    $('#'+id).show();
    $(this).addClass('active').closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
}

});
```

I would also remove the inline styles that set `display:none`.  Then you can in your javascript you can initialize galleria then hide your sections.

Something like:

```
$(function() {

$('#section2, #section3').hide();
$('#section2 .images').galleria();

var sections = $('#section1, #section2, #section3');
function switchid(id, el){  
    sections.hide();
    $('#'+id).show();
    $(this).addClass('active').closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
}

});
```

I would even go further and change your html to be something like this:

```
<ul class="sectionlinks">
<li class="active"><a href="#section1">ONE</a></li>
<li><a href="#section2">TWO</a></li>
<li><a href="#section3">THREE</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="section1" class="section">TEST</div>
<div id="section2" class="section">TEST 2</div>
<div id="section3" class="section">TEST 3</div>
```

Then you javascript could just be:

```
$(function() {

$('#section2 .images').galleria();
$('#section2, #section3').hide();

var sections = $('.section');
$('.sectionlinks a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    sections.hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
});

});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cdaRu/2/

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response.  It probably would makes sense to toggle the divs with jQuery, since I am already loading it on the page.  I've played around with your suggestion a little bit but it doesn't seem to work.  When I start off with implenting your first suggestion, the divs don't toggle. 

Also, when I initiate the galleria, i use: 
jQuery(function() { jQuery('ul.gallery').galleria(); }); 

Can you tell me how that works with your suggestion.

Again, thank you for this.  I'm pretty awful at jQuery and javaScript so this is a big help.

Comment: Wow - thank you so much for setting that up! It works well. The only problem is that it is adding the active class to the anchor instead of the <li>.  Also, it's not actually removing the active class - so as you click on the links, they all remain in the active state. These seem like they would be easy to fix, but I've only managed to completely stop it from working in my attempts thus far.

Comment: Indeed. You rock. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Set them all to 'block' by default, initialize the galleria image gallery, and afterwards hide the divs you want hidden and see if that fixes it. Or try initializing the gallery again after every switchid.

Answer (score 1):

My first recommendation would be to re-write your original Javascript function to use jQuery.  It already has built-in visibility toggle functions ... using the same system will minimize conflicts and make for smoother code.

Answer (score 1):

This is just "off the cuff" but perhaps the box model is incomplete: "The element will generate no box at all" with `display: none;`

Perhaps change that back to "block" and set `visibility: hidden;` would be better?

Comment: The hidden divs have to be set to display: none as I don't want them taking up any space when hidden.

Comment: Was thinking the same - could be that the gallery plugin is throwing an exception since size measures will be 0 when display is none, and thus the rest of the initialization steps are not executed.